# How to check if a string from a column value is present in a list and if a column value is 'Misc' check the list against a column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with a certain string separated by special characters and misc as column values in column label.

I have a list of strings to check it against if the column value has '|' it must check against the list and have the matched string in a new column.

In case the column value is just 'Misc' I would like to check the list against another column and put the matched string in that new column, if its blank the new label can be blank

My available input

```
my_list = ['barbie','hot wheels','american girl']

label                  video_title
barbie| barbie doll   barbie songs
hot wheels| wheels    hot wheels ad
Misc                  barbie
Misc
```

My Expected Output

```
label                   new_label
barbie| barbie doll      barbie
hot wheels| wheels       hot wheels
Misc                     barbie
Misc
```

I had separated the labels with bars and misc to a new data frame to work, How can I write the logic based on these conditions?

Comment: Why the first Misc return barbie 2nd one return blank ?

Comment: Because if its Misc -The list is checked against Video_title column and 1st Misc have a match with Barbie while 2nd Misc does not have anythin in video title to compare with